# jquery autocomplete source option with function returning label and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery 3.3.1 and jQuery-ui 1.12.1.
I have an input field where an user should choose among objects of an array, previously retrieved with an ajax call and stored in a variable.

The documentation of the [source option of autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) says that if a function is provided to filter the terms, it should return an array of strings to make the user choose from.

I'd like to separate the view (the string that I display to the user) from the data, the object beneath it. I've seen that I can return an array of objects `{label: 'string to display', value: the_object}` from the source option, and the label is correctly displayed, but when the user selects it, it turns into an *anonymous* string `[object Object]`.

Having the label string in the input field after the selection would be great, but it could be ok just showing the terms as they are, without any replacement; otherwise I'd like to have the field cleared, and I thought to clear it with:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
  var _content = ui.item;   // Store the content of the field somewhere.
  $(event.target).val('');
}
```

but `.val('')` doesn't work, nor does `.val(null)`.

Here's a test fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/16284/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found, inspired by @CertainPerformance answer, is to store the original dictionary object with a different key, such as `orig_obj`, so that I can then work directly on it in the `select` method.

In this way, the `label` string is displayed when the user selects the label, but we can manipulate the object in its original form.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/16356/

Answer (score 1):

Have the `elements_that_match` object's value be the string you want, not an object.

`elements_that_match.push({"label" : _label, "value" : element_obj});`

to

`elements_that_match.push({"label" : _label, "value" : element_obj.name + ', ' + element_obj.country });`

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/16303/

Comment: I wanted to avoid "re-interpreting" the value back from a string, since I  use it in the select option to populate a form. But you gave me an idea that solved the issue, thanks!